# Call user coordinates, load PHP file, and update UI upon UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I need my app to call a method any time is is "brought back" from not being in the foreground. I am currently doing this with UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification as shown below. The method seems to be calling properly because if I place an alert in my appReturnsActive method, it alerts just fine.

However, instead of a simple alert, in appReturnsActive I am trying to update the UI depending on the user's location. I am passing the user's geocoordinates to a PHP file, and returning a 1 or a 0. if the PHP file returns a 1, I want to show buttons 1 and 2. If the PHP file returns a 0, I want to show buttons 3 and 2.

This doesn't seem to be updating properly every time. Is this because the UI is updating before the app has a chance to find the user's location? Any help would be great!

Thank you!

**ViewDidAppear:**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
selector:@selector(appReturnsActive) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification 
object:nil];
```

**Method called when app comes back up:**

```
- (void)appReturnsActive{

NSString *userLatitude =[(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate 
getUserLatitude];

NSString *userLongitude =[(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate 
getUserLongitude];

NSString *placeLatitude = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                               stringForKey:@"savedLatitude"];    

NSString *placeLongitude = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                stringForKey:@"savedLongitude"];

NSString *distanceURL = [NSString 
stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/location.php?
lat1=%@&lon1=%@&lat2=%@&lon2=%@",userLatitude, userLongitude, placeLatitude, 
placeLongitude];

NSData *distanceURLResult = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL 
URLWithString:distanceURL]];

NSString *distanceInFeet = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:distanceURLResult 
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if ([distanceInFeet isEqualToString:@"1"])
{
    UIBarButtonItem *btnGo = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button 1" 
    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(buttoneOneAction)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnGo;
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:44.0/255.0 
    green:160.0/255.0 blue:65.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnGoTwo = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button 2" 
    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(buttonTwoAction)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnGoTwo;

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:btnGo, btnGoTwo, 
    nil];
}

if ([distanceInFeet isEqualToString:@"0"])
{
    UIBarButtonItem *btnGo = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button 3" 
    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(buttonThreeAction)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnGo;
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:44.0/255.0 
    green:160.0/255.0 blue:65.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnGoTwo = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button 2" 
    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(buttonTwoAction)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnGoTwo;

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:btnGo, btnGoTwo, 
    nil];
}

}
```

**Latitude and Longitude methods in AppDelegate:**

```
- (NSString *)getUserLatitude
{
    NSString *userLatitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", 
    locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude];
    return userLatitude;
}

- (NSString *)getUserLongitude
{
    NSString *userLongitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", 
    locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
    return userLongitude;
}
```

**Location Manager in App Delegate:**

```
- (NSString *)getUserCoordinates
{
    NSString *userCoordinates = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude: %f longitude: %f", 
    locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, 
    locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    return userCoordinates;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of getting the user location is asynchronous, so you need to update the UI only after the user location is obtained. From your current implementation, the UI might be updated before the location is obtained.

You need to implement the delegate of the location manager and do the updating there, for example using NSNotificationCenter:

```
//iOS 5 and before
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    self.currentLocation = newLocation;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CurrentLocationObtained" object:nil];
}

//iOS 6
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

    self.currentLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CurrentLocationObtained" object:nil];
}
```

Based on your current codes, you need to set the AppDelegate as the CLLocationManagerDelegate. Then when you instantiate location manager, set the delegate:

```
locationManager.delegate = self;
```

Take a look here especially on the first answer on how to set the delegate properly: [Set delegate of CLLocationManager (Two different ways, are they equal?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246312/set-delegate-of-cllocationmanager-two-different-ways-are-they-equal)

Comment: Thanks i am using ios6. is that something I would place in the view controller or in my app delegate?

Comment: @Brandon It depends on where you set the delegate of your location manager.

Comment: hi there, i've updated my question to include the collocation manager code from my app delegate. - does this help in specifying what I might need to do to fix this?

Comment: Thanks for your updated response. Is there any way you can tell me how to go about doing those things? Ive looked up how to set the app delegate as the location manager, but can't seem to figure it out. Is this simple to do?

Comment: @Brandon you need to specify CLLocationManagerDelegate in the header. Take a look at the link in my updated answer.